# Build a numeric array in obj-C from a sqlite result set

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sqlite

The following code builds a string array in obj-C from a sqlite DB result set - the data is numeric - however I think I need the array to be a numeric array rather than a string array.

I could use some help with the 'array addObject' line to make the array numeric?

```
        //scan thru result set and add to array
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            [array addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];


        }
```

Comment: can you post the format of the string data please? i.e. how are the numbers separated in the string?

Comment: The data in sqlite are integers.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you at first, my answer below should do what you want.

Comment: An NSMutableArray has no class preference for its elements.  However, if you have a numeric column you want to preserve as numeric you should ask for the numeric value and enclose it in an NSNumber object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

    [array addObject:@(stringValue.integerValue)];
}
```

The `integerValue` method on an NSString will return the numeric value of the string as an `NSInteger`. NSInteger is a primitive type and cannot be inserted into an array. The `@()` around the call to `integerValue` is the literal statement to box a primitive number type into an `NSNumber` object, which can be inserted into an array.

Comment: I edited my answer because I wasn't sure if you could call sqlite3_column_int() on a column that is string data. If that worked I will change my answer back.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I also need to do the same for a floating point field so I assume the following will do it for real numbers:[array addObject:@(sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0))];  Very helpful.